# ENUNCIATE error: cannot access javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding

Tags: maven, jax-rs, enunciate

I have a multi module maven project, recenty I added jaxrs-api dependency to one of them.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

***ENUNCIATE version: 2.0.0.***
When trying maven clean install, I get this error:

```
[WARNING] [ENUNCIATE] [javac] [ERROR] null:-1:-1 error: cannot access javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding
[WARNING] [ENUNCIATE] [javac] error: cannot access javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding
[WARNING] [ENUNCIATE] [javac]   class file for javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding not found
[WARNING] [ENUNCIATE] [javac]   Consult the following stack trace for details.
[WARNING] [ENUNCIATE] [javac]   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding not found
*****
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.13.2:assemble (default) on project API: Enunciate compile failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.13.2:assemble (default) on project API: Enunciate compile failed.
```

I tried to add explicitly InterceptorBinding dependency, but didn't work.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: [`com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.0.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.webcohesion.enunciate/enunciate-maven-plugin) is from 29-Sep-2015. What if you try the latest version `2.13.3`?

Comment: That works along with adding javax.interceptor-api dependency. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[`com.webcohesion.enunciate:enunciate-maven-plugin:2.0.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.webcohesion.enunciate/enunciate-maven-plugin) is from 29-Sep-2015. Use the latest version `2.13.3` instead.